# CentOS 7 GNOME lock screen although all settings say otherwise

Tags: centos, gnome, screen-lock

My CentOS 7.5 VM pops up a blank screen after that is left unused for some time (~15 minutes). When the mouse is moved, it shows a clock in the middle of the screen and requests a password to unlock. This although all settings say otherwise:

*Settings -> Power -> Power Saving -> Blank screen: Never

Settings -> Power -> Power Saving -> Suspend -> Automatic suspend: Off

Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock: Off*

Is there any other setting to change?

GNOME version is 3.25.4.

Comment: It's the Screensaver. In Gnome 2 it is (Menu) > System > Preferences > Look and Feel >> Screensaver : "Lock screen when screensaver is active". ... Gnome 3 : I guess the settings can be found in the Control center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I've incorrectly diagnosed the problem. Inactivity, as per the current  settings, does not trigger the lock screen.

Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, while in the CentOS guest, locks the screen in the CentOS guest *and also* in the Win10 host. It looks like VMware forwards the key combination to the host OS. So the most likely explanation is that I must have locked the screen while in the guest OS.